# EclipseLink Generated id while non-jpa processes are adding records too

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have an `eclipselink` entity with an id column:

```
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;
```

The problem is no matter what generation strategy I use, I get errors because I have an `ETL` tool inserting records and the eclipse link generators do not seem to be able to check for an existing ID before creating a new one.

For example, if the `JPA` generator just generated id 49 for a new record, then the `ETL` tool generates 20 records with ID 50-70, when I create another eclipse link record the generator comes up with 50 for the ID, which has already been used.

How do I handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Your id generation strategy needs to:

1. Be based on something in the database.
2. Get the new id and update the next one atomically and without waiting for commit.
3. Be used by both EclipseLink and your ETL tool.

If you satisfy all three conditions then it should work unless the database itself is not thread safe.

The easiest way to meet these conditions is probably to include `AUTO_INCREMENT` in the column's definition in the database. Another option would be a sequence generator, provided your database supports it, but you would have to make sure the ETL tool uses the sequence rather than, say, finding the max current id and adding 1.

I would guess the ETL tool using its own custom id generation (such as max+1) is your problem.